# Adding validation to a program - JAVA

Tags: java, swing

I have written  the code for a program that asks the user to select a shape, set a number for its radio or width and prints the area of the shape as a result. I am trying to add some validation to it where, for example, the user have to set a number between 10-30 for the radius of the circle and the application continues prompting the user until he/she enters a valid number. I haven't been able to do it so far. Any help?  This is what I have so far:

```
package shapes;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Shapes {

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    mainWindow();
}

private static void mainWindow() {
    int more = 0;
    String[] buttons = {"Circle", "Rectangle", "Triangle"};
    while (more == 0) {

        int userChoice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "Select a Shape", "mainWindow Task 1", 
                1, 3, null, buttons, buttons[2]);

        if (userChoice == 0) {
            userCircle(); 
        } else if (userChoice == 1) {
            userRectangle(); 
        } else if (userChoice == 2) {
            userTriangle(); 
        } else {
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        more = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            "Any other Shape?", "mainWindow Task 1", 2, 3);
    }
}

private static void userCircle() {
    String enteredRadius = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter a number greater than 0 for the radius of the circle. ", "1");
    double radius = Double.parseDouble(enteredRadius);
    Circle userCircle = new Circle(radius);
    double area = userCircle.getArea();
    double perimeter = userCircle.getCircumference();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "A circle with the radius of " + unitTest(radius) + " has\n"
            + "an area of " + unitTest(area) + ",\n"
            + "and a perimeter = " + unitTest(perimeter) + ".");
}


private static void userRectangle() {
    String enteredLength = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter a number greater than 0 for the length of the rectangle. ", "1");
    String enteredWidth = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter a number greater than 0 for the width of the rectangle. ", "1");
    double length = Double.parseDouble(enteredLength);
    double width = Double.parseDouble(enteredWidth);
    Rectangle userRectangle = new Rectangle(length, width);
    double area = userRectangle.getArea();
    double perimeter = userRectangle.getPerimeter();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "A rectangle with a length of " + unitTest(length) + ", and a width of " + unitTest(width) + ",\n"
            + "has an area of " + unitTest(area) + ",\n"
            + "and a perimeter " + unitTest(perimeter) + ".");
}

private static void userTriangle() {
    String userSideA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter a number greater than 0 for the length for side a. ", 3);
    String userSideB = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter a number greater than 0 for the length for side b. ", 4);
    String userSideC = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter a number greater than 0 for the length for side c. ", 5);
    double sideA = Double.parseDouble(userSideA);
    double sideB = Double.parseDouble(userSideB);
    double sideC = Double.parseDouble(userSideC);
    Triangle userTriangle = new Triangle(sideA, sideB, sideC);
    double area = userTriangle.getArea();
    double perimeter = userTriangle.getPerimeter();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A triangle with\n"
            + "a side \"A\" of " + unitTest(sideA) + ",\n"
            + "a side \"B\" of " + unitTest(sideB) + ",\n"
            + "a side \"C\" of " + unitTest(sideC) + ",\n"
            + "has an area of " + unitTest(area)
            + ", and a perimeter of " + unitTest(perimeter));
}

private static String unitTest(double userEntry) {
    if (userEntry == 1) {
        return userEntry + " unit";
    } else {
        return userEntry + " units";
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: `JSpinner` is a convenient way to enforce a limited numeric range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your `userCircle` method to repeat until the input is correct, with a `do-while` loop, for example:

```
private static void userCircle() {

    double radius = 0;
    double area = 0;
    double perimeter = 0;
    do {
        String enteredRadius = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter a number greater than 0 for the radius of the circle. ", "1");
        radius = Double.parseDouble(enteredRadius);
        area = 3.14 * radius * radius; //Change for your Circle.getArea() method
        perimeter = 3.14 * 2 * radius; //Change for your Circle.getPerimeter() method
    } while (radius < 10 || radius > 30);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "A circle with the radius of " + unitTest(radius) + " has\n"
            + "an area of " + unitTest(area) + ",\n"
            + "and a perimeter = " + unitTest(perimeter) + ".");
}
```

However there are better ways to do this, like a [JSpinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) as @trashgod stated in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049554/adding-validation-to-a-program-java/34049774#comment55853847_34049554) above.

I also recommend you to have 1 (and no more) [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) in your app, so whenever you `ALT+TAB` you can see the running app.

Try it and see how it works. Also I might recommend you to post a [Runnable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you *almost* posted one, but it had `Circle`, `Triangle` and `Rectangle` classes which you didn't posted here...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up using the do-while loop but learned a lot about JSpinner which I will be using in the future.

Comment: I'm glad it helped and you actually learned about it JSpinner.